# Odd activity report

Tags: bug, question-lists

On a site's [main-page question list](https://superuser.com/), I see a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1471308/91971) that was recently modified by Davef:
[image]

Yet [Davef's activity page](https://superuser.com/users/1035603/davef?tab=activity) shows nothing on that question and nothing to indicate a pattern of spam:
[image]

I don't see that this user edited the question or did anything else to modify or interact with it.
Is this a bug in the code displaying "modified by" information in the question list? 
(Or, should I conclude that Davef is the first upvoter on that question?)

Comment: This usually occurs and is noticed when a new user posts an NAA which is deleted fast enough. It has nothing to do with voting.

Comment: Or is editing a deleted answer.

Comment: I didn't see any answer by Davef, but if it was deleted super fast, it might have happened.

Comment: They posted an answer and self-deleted ~4 mins later.

Comment: Why are you mentioning "a pattern of spam" in this question? What does that have to do with anything? And how do you know this person has been involved in anything like that?

Comment: @JasonBassford I had hypothesized that if someone posted something spammy it might have gotten autodeleted very quickly and might show up in this way.  However, this didn't seem to be a spam-focused user account, so that led me to believe it was unlikely to be the correct explanation.